# Не работает валидация формы на jquery

Tags: html, jquery, form, валидация

Не работает валидация формы на jquery. Не могу понять почему. В js и jquery я новичок. Валидация нужна только на стороне клиента.

Мой код

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $function() {
    var field = new Array('name', 'phone');

    $('form').submit(function() {
      var error = 0;
      $('form').find('input').each(function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
          if ($(this).attr('name') == field[i]) {
            if (!$(this).val()) {
              $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
              error = 1;
            } else {
              $(this).css('border', 'none');
            }
          }
        }
      })
      if (error = 0) {
        return true;
      } else {
        if (error = 1) var err_text = 'Not all fields are filled!';
        $('.messenger').html(err_text);
        $('.messenger').fadeIn('slow');
        return false;
      }
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="formBlcok">
  <h3>Trial Class</h3>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <p><input value="" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text"></p>
    <p><input value="" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone" type="text"></p>
    <select placeholder="blabla" name=" " id=" ">
   <option value=" ">Chose your class</option>
 </select>
  </form>
  <div class="messenger"></div>
  <button type="submit" name="submit" class="TryI ">Try it</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кнопка отправки формы и блок с сообщением ошибок нужно поместить в саму форму:

```js
var field = new Array('name', 'phone');

$('form').submit(function() {
  var error = 0;
  $('form').find('input').each(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < field.length; i++) {
      if ($(this).attr('name') == field[i]) {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
          $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
          error = 1;
        } else {
          $(this).css('border', 'none');
        }
      }
    }
  });
  if (error = 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    if (error = 1) var err_text = 'Not all fields are filled!';
    $('.messenger').html(err_text);
    $('.messenger').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="formBlcok">
  <h3>Trial Class</h3>
  <form action="" method="POST">
    <p><input value="" name="name" placeholder="Enter your name" type="text"></p>
    <p><input value="" name="phone" placeholder="Enter your phone" type="text"></p>
    <select placeholder="blabla" name="sel" id="sel">
      <option value=" ">Chose your class</option>
    </select>
    <div class="messenger "></div>
    <button type="submit " name="submit " class="TryIt ">Try it</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

---

На самом деле, не пойму, для чего вам цикл в цикле, поэтому код можно сократить до такого вида:

```
$('form').submit(function() {
  var error = 0;
  $(this).find('input').each(function() {
    if (!$(this).val()) {
      $(this).css('border', 'red 1px solid');
      error = 1;
    } else {
      $(this).css('border', 'none');
    }
  });
  if (error = 0) {
    return true;
  } else {
    if (error = 1) var err_text = 'Not all fields are filled!';
    $('.messenger').html(err_text);
    $('.messenger').fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  }
});
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! помогло. Помимо всего этого написанный мною скрипт ломал все остальные скрипты на старице. Я так и не понял почему

Comment: @nirolo1 проверяйте все открывающие и закрывающие скобки, в вашем исходном коде с ними проблема

Comment: Окей, понял, спасибо!